# Graphql: Is there a way to update a query with NEW fields not declared on the schema?

Tags: graphql

So, I have a session query I use to load up on login. Because the load was just too much (yes, loading a TON of application data), I trimmed down this "session" a lot. BUT, the problem I am now having is that when I do a mutation, I can't update the session because it appears that ONLY the fields I declared are updated and everything else from the mutation is ignored.

Note: I want to update from a client side mutation.

So, I have something like this:

```
@graphql(SESSION_QUERY)
class Foo etc....
```

Now, this session has limited data in its schema, like so:

```
query Session {
  session {
    id
    user_id
    first_name
    last_name
    products {
      shoes {
        id
        sizes
      }
      pants {
        id
        sizes
      }
      shirts {
        id
        sizes
      }
    }
  }
```

the amount of data is huge, so I really trimmed it down. Now, my mutations creates a "new" item based on what the user "adds".

Here is the problem, lets say the user "created a shirt", but with THAT mutation the user creates the "sizes", "prices", "coupon codes" etc.. so, I want my "shirt" array in this case, to be updated ala..

```
        update: (store: ApolloStore, results: *) => {
          const data = store.readQuery({ query: SESSION_QUERY });
          const products = data.session.products[productType] || [];
          data.session.products[productType] =
          products.concat(results.data['createProductShirt']);
          store.writeQuery({ query: SESSION_QUERY, data });
        }
```

console.logging before and after the write does infact show the update, BUT the session is never actually updated. It seems it is just filtered to update only the id and sizes. I need the the WHOLE return set updated.

Basically when my component gets new props, the mutation update isn't there.

Is there a way to update this session even when specific values are not defined in the schema?

I'd prefer not to use redux, and my usage seems to be not as evasive as using apollo-link-state (which seems a bit much).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to manually update the apollo store like that - Apollo cache should save everything for you provided that it has the required IDs to make any relations between data.

What does your Apollo cache setup look like in your client?
Have you tried using the [Apollo Dev-tools](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-devtools) to see what is happening in your cache?

Alternatively is [reftechQueries](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html) not enough for you to update the data returned from the Session query?

Comment: I haven't set up a cache yet because well, that seems very heavy handed and my resolvers live on another server.

Comment: I'm talking about a client side cache - like the apollo in memory cache

Comment: correct, I have NOT set that up. I was hoping I could just update the store directly. Does updating the cache force rerenders (I need this) in react components. I have not seen that addressed.

Comment: I would recommend setting that up instead of trying to write to the cache yourself - it will be much easier. You just have to install 1 package and add one line to your client setup: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html

Comment: And to answer your other question: does it force render - Yes it does! It will update the props of any query components and they will re-render. Try it out - it feels a bit like magic

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example on how to write to it? I don;t see it with that link you sent.

Comment: All queries and mutations through the same apollo client will automatically be written to it.. You can also write to it manually if you choose but I think in your usecase you shouldn't need to.
I don't have an example on hand right now but I might be able to help you out tomorrow